# How to use transactions with the Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

When you have code like this:

```
Something something = new Something();
BlahEntities b = new BlahEntities()    
b.AddToSomethingSet(something);
b.SaveChanges();
```

how do run that addition inside a transaction?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can place your code within a Transaction scope

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Your code
    scope.Complete(); //  To commit.
}
```

TransactionScope is in the System.Transactions namespace which is located in the assembly of the same name (which you may need to add manually to your project).

Comment: How is this possible - how does the TransactionScope know about the EF-context, and/or vice-versa?

Comment: TransActionScope is some sort of a wrapper arround everything you can do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Be careful with TransactionScope. It introduces dependencies on MS DTC which is a pain to configure and carries a hefty performance price. Once you have more than one transaction inside the TransactionScope it will initiate a distributed transaction. It will no longer be just a plain DbTransaction running on the used provider.

Also, if you are using a database provider other than Sql Server it is likely it won't support distributed transactions...

Comment: @Miguel, will it be promoted when you have more than one transaction, is it not when a transaction spans more than one database?

Comment: Local transactions are promoted to distributed even if you are querying the same database. If you are using SQL Server 2005 (or above) it will use lightweight transactions before promotion. If you use a provider that does not support promotion you will pay the performance penalty even if doing only one query inside the scope.

Comment: It's not work with multiple context. (eg: OrderContext, ShippingContext)

Answer (score 55):

The ObjectContext has a connection property that you can use to manage transactions.

```
using (var context = new BlahEntities())
using (var tx = context.BeginTransaction())
{
    // do db stuff here...
    tx.Commit();
}
```

In the case of an exception the transaction will be rolled back. Because the call to BeginTransaction() requires and open connection it makes sense to wrap the call to BeginTransaction possibly in an extension method.

```
public static DbTransaction BeginTransaction(this ObjectContext context)
{
    if (context.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        context.Connection.Open();
    }
    return context.Connection.BeginTransaction();
}
```

One scenario where I believe this approach could be useful over TransactionScope, is when you have to access two datasources and only need transactional control over one of the connections. I think that in that case the TransactionScope will promote to a distributed transaction which might not be requiered.

Comment: This no longer works in EF4.1. You have to call `context.Connection.BeginTransaction`.

Comment: @Mikey Cee, it works, you didn't read to end -- Kim introduced extension method. Kim -- you are the man!!! You helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: @Kim, thanks for the assistance, it really helped. However, I want to know if context.Connection.BeginTransaction() escalates to a distributed transaction (MSDTC)? I want to avoid MSDTC, is that possible?

Comment: This is by far my prefered answer because TransactionScope is a pure utopia which is not widely implemented.
@Baig, context.Connection.BeginTransaction() will never ever escalate to a distributed transaction (MSDTC).

Answer (score 9):

I know that for LINQ to SQL, the data context will create a transaction for SubmitChanges() if there is no existing ambient transaction (TransactionScope is an "ambient" transaction). I haven't seen this documented for LINQ to Entities, but I have seen behavior to suggest that it's true for Entity Framework as well.

So as long as you use one SubmitChanges() (L2SQL) or SaveChanges() (Linq to Entities) for all the related changes, you should be OK without using TransactionScope. You need a TransactionScope when

1. Saving multiple changes with multiple SubmitChanges/SaveChanges for one transaction.
2. Updating multiple data sources within one transaction (e.g., Linq and ASP.NET membership SQL provider).
3. Calling other methods that may do their own updates.

I've had trouble with nested TransactionScopes. They're supposed to work, and simple test cases work, but when I get into production code, the "inner" transaction seems to be the same object as the outer transaction. Symptoms include errors that are either "transaction committed, you can't use this transaction any more" or "this transaction object has already been disposed". The errors occur in the outer transaction after the inner transaction has done its work.

Comment: Thanks cyloncat for the long description. What I'm doing is create the record, save it and create a file with the id of the record. Only when the creation of the files succeeds then I commit the transaction. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent example of when and how to use a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Transactions;

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        using(DataContext contextObject = new DataContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            contextObject.Connection.Open();
            // First SaveChange method.
            contextObject.SaveChanges();

            // Second SaveChange method.
            contextObject.SaveChanges();
            //--continue to nth save changes

            // If all execution successful
            scope.Complete();   
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // If any exception is caught, roll back the entire transaction and end the scope.
        scope.Dispose();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close the opened connection
        if (contextObject.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            contextObject.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Find the link below for detailed explanation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. This transaction lasts only long enough to execute the operation and then completes. When you execute another such operation a new transaction is started.
For Newest Entity Framework version: 6.0 +

Read More Here: [EntityFramework and Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx)