# EF TransactionScope and Manually Open/Close Connection Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am wanting to wrap actions into a transaction for each of my users in the DB, and do not want to use MSDTC. Thus, I am trying to manually open a connection for all the transactions to use. Below is a sketch of my code:

```cs
using (var myContext = new Entities())
{
    myContext.Database.Connection.Open();

    var clientQuery = from client in myContext.CustomerMasters
                      where client.CustomerType == (int)Enums.CustomerType.Client
                      select client;

    var clientList = clientQuery.ToList();

    foreach (var client in clientList)
    {
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            FuncCall(myContext, client);
        }
    }
}

void FuncCall(Entities myContext, CustomerMasters client)
{
    // ERROR IS HERE: 
    var alreadyChargedQuery = <LINQ-QUERY>.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I am getting the following exception when this code runs:
[System.Data.EntityException] = {"The underlying provider failed on Open."}

Inner EXception: InnerException = {"Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool."}

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use transactions with the Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054980/how-to-use-transactions-with-the-entity-framework). If not, explain whether your question actually is _"Does Entity Framework support SQL transactions as opposed to MSDTC transactions?"_.

Comment: The possible duplicate, seems to me to not be what I am asking. I'm wondering why I am getting the given exception and how to get the code to properly run without it.